# Spring fmt tags + handlebars.js template + ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am using springs fmt tags do display the date a comment have being posted. Like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate type="both" value="${comment.date}" />
```

This works great for all comments that have already been posted. (Written on page load)

The problem is when dynamically adding a new comment with ajax.

Then I'm using a handlebars template as follows.

```
<script id="new-comment-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="discussion-comment" id="{{id}}">
        <h4 class="inline">
            <small>
                <a href="/users/{{userId}}" class="text-primary inline">{{name}}</a> at {{university}} {{date}}
            </small>
        </h4>
        <form id="command" class="pull-right inline" action="/courses/${course.id}/${course.name}/comment/{{id}}"
              method="post"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
        </form>
        <p>{{{message}}}</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

But my `{{date}}` variable that comes from the server is on the wrong form and if I'm trying

```
<fmt:formatDate type="both" value="{{date}}" />
```

Im getting an error since the value does not exist when the template is being parsed (I guess).

I like to use springs `fmt:formatDate` tag since it handles my internationalisation.

Is it possible somehow?

If not I'm thinking of some alternatives:

1. Keep track of the time on client. Updating it constantly, writing "5min ago", "10min ago" and so on. Until the page is refreshed.
2. Try to send the time in the right format from the server directly. Is it possible to run fmt:formatDate on the server side?

Thank you for you suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Moment.JS](http://momentjs.com/) to be a solution to this.